google.visualization.DataTable() - Adding columns Dynamically to the Data Table
I am trying to create Dynamic DataTable for drawing line chart.
This is my Data Structure for Line chart, In my scenario columns will not be same for all users. For example
User - ABC will have
array_json =
[["date","CA","SF"],
["May-2024",100,200],
["Jun-2024",200,300]]

User - XYZ will have
array_json=
[["date","CA","SF","IL"],
["May-2024",100,200,400],
["Jun-2024",200,300,500]]

I tried creating Data Table like below
dynamic_col_names = array_json.shift(1);
dtbl = new google.visualization.DataTable();
for(var i in dynamic_col_names){
        //console.log(dynamic_col_names[i]);
        if(i==0){
          dtbl.addColumn({label:dynamic_col_names[i],id:dynamic_col_names[i],type:'string'});                
        }
        else{          
          dtbl.addColumn({label:dynamic_col_names[i],id:dynamic_col_names[i],type:'number'});          
        }
      }

I have probelm in adding my column to rows, my code for adding values to data Table
combined[0] = dynamic_col_names;
      for (var i = 1; i < array_json.length; i++){
        var dt_ = convertdate(array_json[i][0]);  // convertdate is function I created to format the date  
// In this Line dt_ column is always fixed, but other number of columns will change based on user
        combined[i + 1] = [dt_,Number(array_json[i][i]),Number(array_json[i][i]),Number(array_json[i][i])];                       
      }  

In this line of code , I want to add this particular column "Number(array_json[i][i])" specific number of times for example user ABC has 2 number data type columns "CA","SF"
combined[i + 1] = [dt_,Number(array_json[i][i]),Number(array_json[i][i])]; 

User XYZ has 3 data type number columns "CA","SF","IL", my code should be loke this
combined[i + 1] = [dt_,Number(array_json[i][i]),Number(array_json[i][i]),Number(array_json[i][i])]; 

How can I do this in an efficient way. Thanks in advance!!

use static method arrayToDataTable()

Thank you @WhiteHat. I tried it works fine.
